# How can I give players extended damage immunity when they respawn?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Minecraft gives about half a second of damage immunity when you take damage. I want to increase it to about 5 minutes on my survival world, but only when you get killed by something or someone. Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: What grace period are you talking about?

Comment: Minecraft does not have a grace period in vanilla. Do you perhaps have a plugin called GriefPrevention on your server? That is a common plugin on many servers that contains a grace period.

Comment: Im talking about that when someone kills you they can't hit you for a small amount of time, or when you join the server/world you won't receive any damage.